# How to read a firebase Data using HTML5 and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

When I want to read the data of my Firebase, nothing appears.

I have tried to read the data using a script for this.

This is my HTML code:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Javascript Firebase</title>
        Humidity: <humidity></humidity><br>
            Clock: <clock></clock><br>
        </head>
        <body>

and this is my script: 

<script type="text/javascript">
        var database = firebase.database('javascript-firebase-6567d');
        var h document.querySelector('humidity');
        var c = document.querySelector('clock');

        var pad = function(x){
        return x < 10 ? '0' +x : x;
        }

        var ShowClock = function() {
        var d = new Date();
        var h = pad(d.getHours());
        var m = pad (d.getMinutes());
        var s = pad (d.getSeconds()); 


        c.innerHTML = [h,m,s].join(':');
        }
        setInterval(ShowClock,1000);

        var myRef = Firebase('https://javascript-firebase-6567d.firebaseio.com/rooms');
        myRef.on('child_changed',function(snapshot){
        data = snapshot.val();
        h.innerHTML = data.humidity;
        });
        </script>
```

The results that I hope is to see the changes that the child "humidity" shows but currently I can not see the results of the clock or the humidity

Comment: It looks like you're using an extremely old version of the Firebase client library. Consider integrating Firebase into your web app using the modern instructions. https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: I already modified it and I have the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
 myRef.on('child_changed',function(snapshot){
    data = snapshot.val();
    h.innerHTML = data.humidity;
 });
```

The `child_changed` event only fires when the data in the location **changes**. If you're trying to show the current child nodes under a location, you'll want to use `child_added`:

```
 myRef.on('child_added',function(snapshot){
    data = snapshot.val();
    console.log(data);
 });
```

The `child_added` fires immediately after attaching the listener for any existing child node, and then subsequently for any new nodes that are added.